# .htaccess blocks urls that contain a dot

Tags: .htaccess

I have this `.htaccess` file

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /



########## Begin - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits
## If you experience problems on your site block out the operations listed below
## This attempts to block the most common type of exploit `attempts` to Joomla!
#
## Deny access to extension xml files (uncomment out to activate)
#
#Order allow,deny
#Deny from all
#Satisfy all
#
## End of deny access to extension xml files
# Block out any script trying to set a mosConfig value through the URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} mosConfig_[a-zA-Z_]{1,21}(=|\%3D) [OR]
# Block out any script trying to base64_encode crap to send via URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode.*\(.*\) [OR]
# Block out any script that includes a  tag in URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\|%3E) [NC,OR]
# Block out any script trying to set a PHP GLOBALS variable via URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
# Block out any script trying to modify a _REQUEST variable via URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
# Send all blocked request to homepage with 403 Forbidden error!
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [F,L]
#
########## End - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (/|\.php|\.html|\.htm|\.feed|\.pdf|\.raw|/[^.]*)$  [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) index.php
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]
```

I don't know why, but if i have a dot in the url, the server shows Url Not Found error instead of redirecting me to the index.php.

I would like to enable urls with dot, how can i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this rule

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (/|\.php|\.html|\.htm|\.feed|\.pdf|\.raw|/[^.]*)$
```

this part `/[^.]*` blocks any dots in request URI. Try to remove it or set to `/[^/.]+`

Seems like this rule `(/|\.php|\.html|\.htm|\.feed|\.pdf|\.raw|/[^.]*)` was intended to allow only urls with a limited set of extensions [.php, .html, .htm, .feed, .pdf, .raw]. But the last part of it `/[^.]*` seems wrong. It checks if after slash there is any symbol except dot. But the rule `[^.]` may contain also slashes. I suppose that the intention of that part was to allow also urls without dots in the last section. So i suggested you to use `/[^/.]+`.

As you want to use dots at any position it is the same like to allow any extension. So This line does not make sense at all.

Comment: It dowsn't work. If i simply delete it, i get a **500 Internal Server Error**. If i change it to `/[^/.]+` It keeps saying that url doesn't exist

Comment: The update is exactly what you written and what i tried, it doesn't work

Comment: @BackSlash what url do you try?

Comment: `http://www.example.com/mai%20t.` but also `http://www.example.com/mai%20.t` doesn't work

Comment: if you want support dots at any position just remove this line

Comment: WOAH! it works! thanks! Can you please tell me what was this line supposed to do and (eventually) what will not work as expected with it's removal? thanks!